# Tensorflow: GPU memory exhuastion and max pool layers

Tags: gpu, tensorflow

I have a pretty simple CNN setup (3 convolution layers into a fully connected layer) , using a Geforce GTX 960 GPU with 4GB of memory. I was hitting a GPU resource exhausted issue, and while playing around I discovered if I put a pooling layer (which reduces the overall size of the layer by a factor of 4) it actually made the problem worse. In other words, I was hitting the resource exhausted, and then after removing the pooling layer, I was able to train. I intuitively thought that since a pooling layer would reduce the number of operations downstream during the optimization piece of the training that it would help the memory constraints. Does any know how a max pooling layer could potentially add operations and increase memory like this?

Comment: Some code might be helpful to see how you are constructing the model. Why do you think adding pooling reduces the number of parameters? Doesn't the pool layer add new parameters? Back propagation still moves through the pooling layer into the convolution layers during training right?

Comment: It is suspicious that a small CNN is using this much memory. Is there something else hogging your GPU?